# UITextView text jumps up and down after applying contentInset

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextview

I am applying contentInset (bottom) on UITextView because the text gets hidden because of the keyboard. But it seems like UITextView glitches after text height increases to certain level when you apply contentInset.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    var textView: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        textView = MyTextView(usingTextLayoutManager: true)
        
        textView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        
        textView.contentInset.bottom = 300
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        textView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(textView)
        
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        [   textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ].forEach {
            $0.isActive = true
        }
        
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        
        self.loadText()
    }
    
    func loadText() {
        let nsmutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(
            string: "Hello World!",
            attributes: [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold)
        ])
        
        textView.textStorage.setAttributedString(nsmutableAttributedString)
    }
}
```

**Things I have tried -**

I tried to replace contentInset with textContainerInset.

```
textView.textContainerInsets.bottom = 300
```

This solves the glitch but takes away the auto scrolling behaviour as you type.

Can you tell me if there is an alternative solution for this which works properly ?